# SQL Counting values from joined tables

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have two Tables which i want to query from:

The first one is called `bugs` and has columns:

```
bg_id , bg_project , bg_reported_date
```

The second one is called `Projects` and has columns:

```
pj_id , pj_name , pj_parent_id
```

The `bg_project` of `bugs` represents the `pj_id` of the `Projects`.

I want to count how many bg_id i had in a single month for every parent project.
What would the query should be to get results that would look like: `ProjectParentName , Count`

A parent project can't have another parent project.
If a project is a parent project then it will have the same pj_id as the pj_parent_id.
Here's an example:

```
pj_id   pj_name     pj_parent_id

1       Parent1     1
2       Child1      1
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? Semi-shot in the dark. Haven't done SQL in awhile.

```
SELECT COUNT(bugs.bg_project) AS BugCount,
       bugs.bg_reported_date AS BugReportDate,
       Projects.pj_name as ProjectParentName, 
       Projects.pj_id AS ProjectID 
FROM bugs
JOIN Projects
WHERE ProjectID = bugs.bg_project
AND (BugReportDate BETWEEN to_date('YEAR/2digitmonth/01','yyyy/mm/dd')
                   AND to_date('YEAR/2digitmonth/lastday','yyyy/mm/dd'));
```

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for your answer but i am afraid its not what i was looking for. Have a look on the comment i did above for NePh's answer.

Comment: Are you using a [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model) for this table? Perhaps you should look into a [different method for hierarchial structuring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
WITH    bugsInPeriod
          AS ( SELECT   *
               FROM     bugs
               WHERE    MONTH(bg_reported_date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
             )

    SELECT   pParent.pj_name AS ProjectParentName ,
             COUNT(bg_id) AS [Count]
    FROM     Projects pParent
             INNER JOIN Projects pChild ON pParent.pj_id = pChild.pj_parent_id
             LEFT JOIN bugsInPeriod b ON pChild.pj_id = b.bg_project
    WHERE    pParent.pj_id = pParent.pj_parent_id
    GROUP BY pParent.pj_name
    ORDER BY pParent.pj_name
```

Replace the `MONTH(GETDATE())` with the desired month number, e.g. `2` if you want February.
The `ORDER BY` is optional.

In order to display projects with no bugs as well we need the `LEFT JOIN`. The `WHERE`-clause has to be in a subselect, otherwise it would eliminate the projects with no bugs.

**Edit:** I updated the query. I think it should now get the desired results.

Comment: Hi NePh, thanks for your answer but it is not exactly what i need.
My problem comes with the parent project name.
Let me give you an example.
Lets say we have 1 parent project that has 2 child projects.
This will be in the projects table as:
1, parent name , 10 ||
2, child 1 name , 10 || 3, child 2 name , 10 .
So the problem is that i need to count all the bugs under a parent project ( which includes ofc all the childs too ) and display the parent name next to the count.

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood your question.  

Can a parent project have parent project?  
If yes is there a limit of levels?
And which value is in pj_parent_id if thers is no parent? 
NULL I guess?

Comment: Hi NePh,
No a parent project can't have an other parent project. If a project is a parent project then it will have the same pj_id as the pj_parent_id.
So if a project doesn't have any chield projects it will automatically be a parent project (of it self).
Hope this makes sense.
Thanks for your help btw.